# Can't import backup file

Tags: dbeaver

Linux Mint 20.1

DBaver 22.1.4

I try to restore PostgreSQL from backup file.

But I get error:

```
/run/user/1000/doc/65139af1/bin/pg_restore --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=myUserName --format=c --dbname=myDB/home/alex/postgresql.backup
Task 'PostgreSQL restore' started at Thu Dec 15 14:49:01 EET 2022
/run/user/1000/doc/65139af1/bin/pg_restore: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Task 'PostgreSQL restore' finished at Thu Dec 15 14:49:01 EET 2022
2022-12-15 14:49:01.945 - IO error: Process failed (exit code = 127). See error log.
2022-12-15 14:49:01.947 - java.io.IOException: Process failed (exit code = 127). See error log.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.validateErrorCode(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:242)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.tasks.PostgreDatabaseRestoreHandler.validateErrorCode(PostgreDatabaseRestoreHandler.java:151)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.executeProcess(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:223)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.doExecute(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:262)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.lambda$0(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:83)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.RunnableContextDelegate.lambda$0(RunnableContextDelegate.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1):

check library libpq.so.5 it is installed or not, check use command in your terminal

> ldconfig -p | grep libpq.so.5

if installed, you will see
[image]

try this :

[image]

Comment: idconfig -p | grep libpq.so.5

Result is: 
 libpq.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5

Comment: i just update my answer, check it

Comment: Not help. Same error. 

sudo find / -name  libpq.so.5 and result is:

/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
/usr/lib/libpq.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5